# Remove CiviCRM and Drupal links / banner on profile form

Tags: drupal, profile, header-footer

we have setup an online profile form that new members to our charity can complete. The information then pulls directly into CiviCRM.

When accessing the profile / form online there are drupal and CiviCRM headers / footers and links on there that we would prefer to remove:

[image]

[image]

Is anybody aware of a way to do this?

Many thanks

.............................................................

Thanks for your help guys it has been extremely useful and and I have now removed the links / logo's in the footer.

Unfortunately however I am still struggling to remove the logo and the "Home" link from the header, as per below:

[image]

I have tried unticking the logo option under www.yoursite.com/admin/appearance however this did not seem to make a difference (I am happy for it to be removed from public and private / internal view so any option to get rid of it is fine :)). It would also be great if we can remove the "Home" link.
We have our pulbic theme as CiviCRM Seven if that is any help at all.

Finally is there a way to change the background colour of the public profile / site - Currently it is just blank / white so it would be great to add the colour of our main website theme into there.

Thanks again for all your great help, Terry

.....................................

As per the image below the logo option has been unticked but the logo and home link are still present.

[image]

Comment: You are using CiviCRM seven theme the logo is not rendered from UI settings. You will need to turn off by adding css. I have posted the css in my answer.

Comment: Thank you - This has now resolved the problem. Thank you for taking the time to come back to me, so happy to have this now up and running correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain things can be turned off from UI but others needs to be hidden by css

1. Since you want to hide this option on public facing forms than you can switch the theme from using CiviCRM Seven to use your default one by navigating to Appearance(/admin/appearance).  Scroll down and change the 'CiviCRM Public theme' right at the bottom of the page to use your default theme. (If you have CiviCRM theme module enabled)

If not 1 than

2. Hide Logo from header - You will need to add below css in CiviCRM seven theme  styling file to hide the logo

>

```
body.page-civicrm #branding {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

3. empowered by CiviCRM - This can be disabled by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administrator >> System Settings >> Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.). Change the option for 'Display "empowered by CiviCRM"' to and save the form.

[image]

4. Powered By Drupal - Is a Drupal block which can be disabled by navigating to Structure >> Blocks. Scroll down and find 'Powered by Drupal' and change the corresponding drop down option to none and save.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 8):

To remove the Drupal footer (This is a block called - Powered by Drupal) –

www.yoursite.com/admin/structure/block/manage/system/powered-by/configure

Under region settings, set all to - None

To remove empowered by CiviCRM –

www.yoursite.com/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1

Set Display "empowered by CiviCRM" to No

For the header, that’s the logo, which can be changed/removed from the CiviCRM public theme –

www.yoursite.com/admin/appearance